# How to filter list of syscalls only to specific process name?

Tags: macos, trace, dtrace

I've the following dtrace one-liner:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry { @num[probefunc] = count(); }'
```

which prints number of syscall count by program (after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

How do I add filter above probe to only apply to a process by its name (e.g. `php`)? Similar to `dtruss -n <name>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is fairly straight forward, since it can be checked in `dtruss` how the filtering is done:

```
$ grep -C5 NAME $(which dtruss)
syscall:::entry
/(OPT_command && pid == $target) || 
 (OPT_pid && pid == PID) ||
 (OPT_name && NAME == strstr(NAME, execname)) ||
 (OPT_name && execname == strstr(execname, NAME)) ||
 (self->child)/
{
  /* set start details */
```

where `NAME` is the process name.

So the one-liner command is (replace `php` with your process name):

```
sudo dtrace -n '
  inline string NAME = "php";
  syscall:::entry
  /(NAME == strstr(NAME, execname)) || (execname == strstr(execname, NAME))/
{ @num[probefunc] = count(); }
'
```

Comment: On a Mac you could simply `/execname=="php"/`